# Windows DNS suffix frustration

Tags: windows, networking, dns

So previously we had two batches of equipment hosted at our server provider;

1. Pre-cloud dedicated servers, DNS suffix `company.com`
2. Private-cloud instances located in Dallas, DNS suffix `dfw.company.com`

Having outgrown the DFW datacenter we got a new batch of private cloud gear in Virginia to which we've assigned the DNS suffix `iad.company.com`.

The trouble is that there are some things with the same name in both DFW and IAD, eg: our moitoring box, `omd`. Now, I *should* be able to specify the hostname as simply `omd.iad` or `omd.dfw` and have the completion fall through to the `company.com` suffix. This is what is happening in my Linux VM.

However, when trying to connect to these hosts in Windows I cannot use a short name like `omd.iad` at all. The Windows DNS client appears to take the presence of a dot in the hostname as an indication that it is a FQDN, despite the documentation stating that that should only happen when the the hostname *ends* with a dot. eg: `omd.iad.`

Is there any way to make the Windows DNS client behave properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through more Google results just for ballpark areas in the registry to dig around in I found an article that referred to a section in Group Policies that ended up containing the relevant knob to make the DNS client function properly.

So:

1. `gpedit.msc`
2. Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > DNS Client
3. Set "Allow DNS Suffix Appending to Unqualified Multi-Label Name Queries" to Enabled.